# What is it called when you use wrong but smart arguments?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call it when someone uses smart and intelligent but wrong statements to strengthen their argument?

Comment: How do wrong statements strengthen their argument?

Comment: Closely related: [to blind someone with science {UK mainly}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282538/to-blind-someone-with-science-not-known-or-rare-in-the-us).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A word like propaganda but maybe not quite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210851/a-word-like-propaganda-but-maybe-not-quite), a request for specious, wonderful-sounding propositions which are actually found to be wrong on close examination. _Hokum_ is offered as an answer.

Comment: The Lexico definition of 'specious' is applicable, and was given at [a word to describe writing that only contains superficial knowledge and no genuine ... It means more than shallow. It means there is an effort to sound knowledgeable on the topic. Almost like there's an element of "faking" knowledge.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504412/word-to-describe-writing-that-only-contains-superficial-knowledge-and-no-genuine/504469#504469).

Comment: Perhaps an even closer fit is [Is there a phrase or word that describes misinformation expressed in an articulate way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397439/is-there-a-phrase-or-word-that-describes-misinformation-expressed-in-an-articula/397442#397442)  @DJClayworth's 'sophistry' facilitated the reverse search, and is the closest fit for an answer. But already given.

Comment: Please include an example sentence where you would use the word.

Answer (score 16):

**Sophistry** is

> [The use of clever but false arguments, especially with the intention of deceiving.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sophistry)

This seems to fit your definition.

Answer (score 6):

Specious

A 'specious argument' is one that is empty, false or incorrect.

Definition:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speci

Comment: I had hoped to discourage another 'specious' answer to virtually the same question as in previous threads, by giving it in a 'comment' rather than as an 'answer'.

Comment: Well, 'specious' is about the best word that I know, to answer this question. And seeing as how putting answers in comments doesn't result in... answered questions, what is the point of answering questions in comments? @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Or, almost even worse... not answering them ✨

Comment: We're supposed to do housekeeping on ELU; the ultimate aim is to build up a repository of good analysis / practice, not be a Q and A service that generates so many duplications that the repository is useless as a reference.

Comment: Well, is it a duplicate, or not? An answered duplicate is presumably better than an unanswered duplicate, in that it might actually... help somebody.  Sorry I am not genius in housekeeping. 

Comment: That was English understatement

Comment: About the housekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

All definitions are from Merriam-Webster.  Words for this include **shrewd**

> **b** : given to wily and artful ways or dealing

Or **wily**

> : full of wiles : crafty

Or **crafty**

> **2a** : adept in the use of subtlety and cunning

Or **slick**

> **1b** : having surface plausibility or appeal : glossy
>
> **2a** : characterized by subtlety or nimble wit : clever

Or **cunning**

> **1** : dexterous or crafty in the use of special resources (such as skill or knowledge) or in attaining an end
>
> **2** : characterized by wiliness and trickery
>
> **3** : prettily appealing : cute
>
> **4** : displaying keen insight

Or **sly**

> **2a** : clever in concealing one's aims or ends

Or **clever**, in a context where it implies dishonesty

> **2** : marked by wit or ingenuity

Or **manipulative**, from **manipulate**

> **b** : to control or play upon by artful, unfair, or insidious means especially to one's own advantage

**Casuistry** can mean either a form of theological reasoning about ethics, or, more often:

> **2** : specious argument : rationalization

This is sometimes applied to specific, extant religious orders, but that would be considered offensive.  **Apologetics** is also sometimes used neutrally as theological terms, but in other contexts, has a negative connotation of a lawyerly defense of the indefensible.  An **apologia** can mean this too, but sometimes has a positive connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Sophistry, as found by DJClayworth, is what you're looking for, but I think bullsh*t is another acceptable answer.